# Prolog - Split one list into 2 which contain all the members of the original one in any order

Tags: list, split, prolog

I'm not really good with lists in Prolog. What I'm trying to do is to split one list `[1,2,3,4]` into two lists. The catch is that the elements of those two lists can be in any order.

This is what I have right now:

```
divideList([],[],[]).
divideList(L1,L2,[H|T]) :-
    select(H,L1,L1C),
    length(L1,Length1),
    length([H|T],LengthHT),
    Length1 =< LengthHT,
    divideList(L1C,L2,T).
divideList(L1,L2,[H|T]) :-
    select(H,L2,L2C),
    length(L2,Length2),
    length([H|T],LengthHT),
    Length2 =< LengthHT,
    divideList(L1,L2C,T).
```

It works when I put in all the lists and it just has to check if it's true or false.

```
?- divideList([1,2],[4,3],[1,2,3,4]).
true .
?- divideList([2,1],[4,3],[1,2,3,4]).
true .
?- divideList([2,1],[3,4],[1,2,3,4]).
true .
```

However if I try to do this:  `?- divideList(A,[3,4],[1,2,3,4]).`

It shows me this `ERROR: Out of global stack` .

When I want it to show me this:

```
?- divideList(A,[3,4],[1,2,3,4]).
A = [1,2] ;
A = [2,1].
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify it a bit using `permutation/2`:

```
divideList([A|As], [B|Bs], L) :-
    permutation(L, P),
    append([A|As], [B|Bs], P).
```

The `[A|As]` and `[B|Bs]` prevent `[]` from being a solution for the first or second argument.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need.